# Is there a way to mutate categories through GraphQL for a specific siteId?

Tags: categories, graphql, craft4

The graphQL does not support `siteId` parameter in category mutation. How could I mutate the content for a specific siteId?

Answer (score 1):

Categories aren't stored by site, they're stored globally. That's why the site ID isn't available. If you want separate categories per site, you'll need to create multiple category groups.